# Cannot connect Oracle 32bit on X64 machine

Tags: oracle, toad, plsqldeveloper

I have installed the Oracle Client 10.2.1 32bit in an X64 WIN7 laptop. I have Installed also TOAD and PLSQLDeveloper but both of them are not working and the error is: ORA-12154:TNS could not resolved the connection idebrified. While with the NET MANAGER I can connect with the database.
Any idea how can I resolve this big issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the parenthesis in the folder in which the client application has been installed (x86).

More detail and solutions can be found [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3455198)

Answer (score 0):

The error TNS could not resolve service name usually means that the client is not able to find the tnsnames.ora file. There are several locations where the clients tries to find it, one of the first locations is in %ORACLE_HOME%/network/admin
Better is to define a environment variable TNS_ADMIN and make that point to a directory where the sql*net files are located.
you can use `tnsping your_service_name` to check the resolution.